# Populate table using PUT command through snowsql not working

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, put

I am trying to put a csv file on my local machine to snowflake table stage through snowflake PUT

Command used :

```
put file://C:\Users\utkamishra\Downloads\data.csv @%mytable;
```

Have create a table named mytable in snowflake current database and schema as well.

But this throws me error while running through snowsql
253003 (n/a): HEAD with url https://uxgs0psfcb1stg.blob.core.windows.net/tableszz6a26dba5-2df0-432b-be6e-0f836616ef95/test.csv.gz?sv=2020-08-04&spr=https&se=2021-11-24T21%3A39%3A40Z&sr=c&sp=rwdl&sig=B5ndBLYCL%2Fgc4ep%2FU7gdAbk30DYIhjEHPfjSIlwR9nE%3D failed for exceeding maximum retries.

Can anyone help how can I put my csv file from local to snowflake for populating my table using snowsql.

Comment: Can you just upload it to the internal stage at **@~**; ? Also can you enable DEBUG mode with SnowSQL and provide a snippet from the log? The error suggests you are not able to reach the Azure blob, do you maybe have a proxy in between?

Comment: Why do I need to enter Azure blob? Its internal to Snowflake right. But otherwise how can I check if my authentication is working or not because I am able to login into my company blob storage accounts on azure.

Comment: I didn't mean you personally to enter Azure blob, but when you use PUT with a destination of a stage (@~) then SnowSQL will try to connect to that stage which has an Azure blob behind. Are you able to connect with SnowSQL to your Snowflake account? If yes, then it is not an authentication issue, that has a different error. I am suspecting a connectivity issue rather than authentication. Can you run [SnowCD](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/snowcd.html) and see if it passes all tests?

Comment: For SnowSQL follow this [article](https://community.snowflake.com/s/article/How-to-generate-log-file-on-Snowflake-connectors#snowsql) to get log level set to DEBUG. For SnowCD, what exactly are you unable to follow? Have you installed it?

Comment: in the log file i get this message :
253003 (n/a): HEAD with url https://mnrkmhsfcb1stg.blob.core.windows.net/userszz0d399107-ac89-430b-9af2-a0f487b5c568/mock_customer_profiles.csv.gz?sv=2020-08-04&spr=https&se=2021-11-30T09%3A50%3A29Z&sr=c&sp=rwdl&sig=gLkpQEZjCYsC%2Fzf9WNomrjOcDomMOWtITzaokZ8gHI4%3D failed for exceeding maximum retries.
@Sergiu

Comment: Do you have a proxy in between? Has SnowCD passed all tests? To me it looks like something is blocking network access to the internal stage.

Comment: Yes all Snowcd checks have passed. 

PS C:\Users\utkamishra> snowcd.exe C:\Users\utkamishra\Downloads\allowlist.json
Performing 24 checks for 9 hosts
All checks passed
PS C:\Users\utkamishra>

I do have VPN but I have tried disabling that, it still gives me the same error